# 403 error accessing HTTPS web service (restful)

Tags: asp.net, rest, web-services, iis

Our security team recently change the service to become HTTPS (from http).

We can hit the main svc page, but accessing methods gives a 403 error now.

We tested it using Postman - do we need to configure the request differently now that it is HTTPS?

thanks.

Comment: No, generally, you don't need to change config. Did you try setting a breakpoint in the handler? Is it executed?

Comment: Read IIS log files and learn the sub status code please, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0